# BEFORE UPDATE trigger preventing all updates

Tags: mysql, triggers, mariadb

I have a table with many columns, and I am trying to implement a trigger that works **before the update** on a specific column to ensure that the values of that specific column can only be changed according to a specific transition, from 1 to 2 to 3.

For example, if a value is 1 in my column, an update on that column will be rejected if there is an attempt to change it from 1 to 3, but accepted if it changes from 1 to 2.

The code below works, however, it current rejects ALL updates which do not conform to that. For example, if I attempt to update the rows of a different column within that table, my update will be rejected, even if I have not changed the value column in any way.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER transition BEFORE UPDATE ON tbl
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF (OLD.value = 1 AND NEW.value != 2)
OR (OLD.value = 2 AND NEW.value != 3)
SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Incorrect transition of values';
END IF;
END //
DELIMITER;
```

How can I fix this so that I can establish transition consistency while still being able to update the other columns?

I am using mariadb 5.5.50.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will allow the values to stay unchanged:

```
CREATE TRIGGER transition BEFORE UPDATE ON tbl
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF (OLD.value = 1 AND NEW.value NOT IN (1, 2))
  OR (OLD.value = 2 AND NEW.value NOT IN (2, 3))
  THEN
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
    SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Incorrect transition of values';
  END IF;
END//
```

I tested this:

```
mysql> insert into tbl set value=1, other=11;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> update tbl set other=22;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

mysql> update tbl set value=1, other=33;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

mysql> update tbl set value=2, other=44;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

mysql> update tbl set value=1, other=55;
ERROR 1644 (45000): Incorrect transition of values

mysql> update tbl set value=2, other=66;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

mysql> update tbl set value=2, other=77;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

mysql> update tbl set value=3, other=88;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0
```

But what happens after the value is 3? Can it change to anything, or must it stay 3? You might need another term to test for that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I want to be able to change the values in that specific column from 1 --> 2 or 2 --> 3, but reject any changes which do not conform to that transition (e.g., 1 --> 3 [UPDATE tbl SET value = 3 WHERE value = 1, should be rejected). Currently, my trigger manages this, but the issue is that I can't update any other column in my table, even if they don't change anything in 'value'. How can I fix this?

Comment: The solution I provided works with your requirements in mind. I edited my answer above to include a demonstration of testing it.